# How do I sort a three dimensional array in PHP with array_walk?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Advanced Hip Hop Ages 10+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436902200
                    [end] => 1436905800
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Intermediate Hip Hop Ages 9+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436899500
                    [end] => 1436902200
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Beginning Pointe Ages 10+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436896800
                    [end] => 1436899500
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Int/Adv Ballet  Ages 10+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436889600
                    [end] => 1436896800
                    [capacity] => 15
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Beginning Ballet 8+ year olds
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436884200
                    [end] => 1436891400
                    [capacity] => 15
                    [students] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Intermediate Technique/Progressions Ages 9+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436899500
                    [end] => 1436904900
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Int/Adv Tap Ages 9+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436895900
                    [end] => 1436899500
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Beginning Jazz/Contemporary Technique Ages 8+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436887800
                    [end] => 1436893200
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Int/Adv Jazz 9+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436893200
                    [end] => 1436898600
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Int/Adv Ballet Barre Ages 9+
                    [session] => 0
                    [start] => 1436886000
                    [end] => 1436889600
                    [capacity] => 
                    [students] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

I would like to sort the the third level of the array (the classes) by their start time. I have tried a number of different solutions suggested on here for two level arrays, to no avail.

My latest attempt is:

```
array_walk($schedule, 'walk_cmp');

function walk_cmp($array, $key){
    usort($array, function($a, $b) { 
      return ($a['start'] > $b['start']) ? -1: 1;
    });
}
```

I have confirmed that the sort is working within `walk_cmp` but those changes to the array are not then reflected in the main array.

I feel I must be missing something obvious, but here I am. Keep in mind, that this is an exemplary array that is dynamic in nature. It will always have this structure but the amount of elements in the second (Day) and third (Class) array will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt looks good and you are also very close to the solution!

Your main problem is, that you sort your array in the function as local variable. So your original array won't get changed. You have to pass the array [by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) So your code will look something like this:

```
array_walk($schedule, "walk_cmp");

function walk_cmp(&$array, $key) {
                //^ See here
    uasort($array, function($a, $b) { 
        if($a['start'] == $b['start']) //If they are the same, return 0
            return 0;
        return ($a['start'] > $b['start']) ? -1 : 1;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concise and modern ways to do this:

1. `array_walk()` with `array_multisort()` and `array_column()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PeSjL))

   ```
   array_walk($array, function(&$v) {
       array_multisort(array_column($v, 'start'), $v);
   });
   ```

   This modifies by reference as it iterates the first level of array, then the second level is sorted based on the targeted column in the third level.  `array_multisort()` also modifies by reference.
2. `array_walk()` with `usort()` and a three-way comparison operator (affectionately named the "spaceship operator") ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m6nFQ))

   ```
   array_walk($array, function(&$a1) {
       usort($a1, function($a2, $b2) {
           return $a2['start'] <=> $b2['start'];
       });
   });
   ```

   **From PHP7.4**, arrow function syntax can be used to reduce the overall syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eFcqT))

   ```
   array_walk($array, function(&$a1) {
       usort($a1, fn($a2, $b2) => $a2['start'] <=> $b2['start']);
   });
   ```

   You can even reduce the `array_walk()` syntax to form a one-liner: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ftYfO))

   ```
   array_walk($array, fn(&$a1) => usort($a1, fn($a2, $b2) => $a2['start'] <=> $b2['start']));
   // array_walk silently ignores the data returned by the "arrow"
   ```